# two sample t-test not matching R

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to do a hypothesis test and I've been told that my alternative hypothesis is that male students are older on average than female students in this particular survey.
I've set it up as follows:

H(alternative): u1 > u2
H(null): u1 < u2

my n1  = 24, n2 = 32

s1 = 3.27042

s2 = 1.840133

sample mean 1 = 21.5

sample mean 2 = 20.03125

My variances are also unequal so I am using this test:

[image]

my S^2 spooled I found was 6.499 (3dp)

so when I came to finding t-statistic I did the following:

t = (21.5 - 20.03125) / sqrt((6.499/24) + (6.499/32))

and got a t value of 2.13359

however in R I am getting a t-value of 1.9778. Is this just a rounding error on my end or have I done something wrong in my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The hypotheses are

$H_0:U_1 = U_2$

and $H_a: U_1 > U_2$

I a two sample t-test, you are assuming the U_1-U_2 = 0 and the formula in the numerator is just $(\bar X_1 - \bar X_2) - (U_1-U_2)$ and the later is zero according to your hypothesis. U_1 and U_2 are the population means  and you don't need them.

An example of this is as follows.
Male Height: $$\bar X_1 = 564.9, n_1 = 10, s_1^2 = 21544.76667$$

Female Height:    $$\bar X_2 = 484.5, n_2 = 10, s_2^2 = 17221.16667$$

$s_p^2 = \dfrac{(n_1-1)S_1^2 + (n_2-1)S_2^2}{(n_1 + n_2-2)} = 19382.96667$

```
                       $alpha = .05$
```

Hypothesis
        $H_0 :  \mu_2 = \mu_1$
        $H_a :  \mu_2 > \mu_1$

Test Statistic:

$$ t = \dfrac{\bar x_2- \bar x_1}{\sqrt{s_p^2/n}} = - 1.82619$$

The test statistic is distributed as Student's t distribution with $(n_1+n_2-2)$ degrees of freedom.

```
    (b) Decision rule
```

With alpha = .05 and df , find the t-critical.  We reject H0 if t > t_critical.

(6) Statistical decision

We reject $H_0$ because t-statistic > t-critical and conclude that the males are on average taller than females.

Something of this sort.

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Thanks Satish, are you sure the null hypothesis is u1 = u2? I thought it was u1 <= u2? or is this the same thing. Also I forgot to mention that my variances are unequal so I am using the other 2 sample t-test with s^2 spooled. I will edit my working so you can see. I am getting different results than my statistics program

Comment: It does not make a difference it is the alternate hypothesis that will need inequlaity sign. No problem, I will take a look at your edit after you complete. I don't understand why you would say variaces are different. It is supposed to be different for two groups.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry if it seems like a completely different question, but I've taken what you've said about the 'u'

Comment: Any success? @satish ramanathan

Comment: I find your calculation correct. It can't be rounding error. Is the t-value that you are seeing is the critical value and not the test statistic?  Have you input the data properly.  Do other measures agree? such as means and sample standard deviation and things like that.  Make a quick check. If everything is right then you may have to check for R's notes on its formulae

Comment: Yeah everything looks ok in R, only thing that might be different is the DF=33.805?

Comment: DF, you mean degrees of freedom to calculate pooled variance

Comment: yes degrees freedom

Comment: This is what the summary looks like: http://i.imgur.com/ohiNTZ3.png

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test, It calculates t-statistic in a different way. I calculated it and it is 1.9778.  So you are correct in your way.  However, what has been taught in the class is what you should follow and not R

Comment: If you find my answer useful and my investigation useful, please and vote and accept the answer.

Comment: I dont quite understand why welches formula there is the same as the normal 2 sample t-test? This was in my notes: http://i.imgur.com/PhFdO6v.png